# what's difference between simple_query_string and query_string?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I had a nested field `source` in my index seems like this:

```
"source": [    
    {
        "name": "source_c","type": "type_a"
    },
    {
        "name": "source_c","type": "type_b"
    }
]
```

I used `query_string` query and `simple_query_string` query to query `type_a` and got two different result.

**query_string**

```
{
  "size" : 3,
  "query" : {
    "bool" : {
      "filter" : {
        "query_string" : {
          "query" : "source:\"source.type:=\"type_a\"\""
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I got **163459** hits in 294088 docs.

**simple_query_string**

```
{
  "size": 3,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "simple_query_string": {
          "query": "source:\"source.type:=\"type_a\"\""
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I got **163505** hits in 294088 docs.

I only made three different types `type_a`,`type_b`,`type_c` randomly. So I had to say **163459** and **163505** were very little difference in **294088** docs.

I noly got one info in [Elasticsearch Reference [2.1]](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/query-dsl-simple-query-string-query.html)

> Unlike the regular query_string query, the simple_query_string query will never throw an exception, and discards invalid parts of the query.

I don't think it's the reason to make the difference.

I want to know what make the little different results between `query_string` and `simple_query_string`?

Comment: what is the mapping of field `type`?

Comment: string and not_analyzed

Comment: The query string you're using seems weird (`source:\"source.type:=\"type_a\"\"`) as you're using the `source` field twice. Are you sure about your syntax? Moreover, you need to know that `simple_query_string` doesn't use the same query syntax as `query_string`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, `nested query syntax` is not supported for either `query_string` or `simple_query_string`. It is an [open issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/11322), and this is the [PR](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/11339) regarding that issue.

Then how are you getting the result? Here [Explain API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/search-explain.html) will help you understand what is going on. This query

```
{
  "size": 3,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "simple_query_string": {
          "query": "source:\"source.type:=\"type_a\"\""
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

have a look at the output, you will see

```
"description": "ConstantScore(QueryWrapperFilter(_all:source _all:source.type _all:type_a)),
```

so what is happening here is that ES looking for term *source* , *source.type* **or** *type_a*, it finds *type_a* and returns the result.
You will also find something similar with `query_string` using `explain api`

Also `query_string` and `simple_query_string` have different syntax, for e.g `field_name:search_text` is not supported in `simple_query_string`.

Correct way to query nested objects is using [nested query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-query.html)

**EDIT**

This query will give you desired results.

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "source",
      "query": {
        "term": {
          "source.type": {
            "value": "type_a"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 3):

[Acording to the documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/query-dsl-simple-query-string-query.html#_simple_query_string_syntax) `simple_query_string` is meant to be used with **unsafe input**.

So that users can enter anything and it will **not throw exception** if input is invalid. Will simply discard invalid input.